# convert multidimensional array from viewmodel to javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have following ViewModel

```
public class IndexViewModel
    {
        public string[,] Table1 { get; set; }
    }
```

In controller I populate this property

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = new IndexViewModel();
            model.Table1 = new string[6, 7] {
              { "", "Kia", "Nissan", "Toyota", "Honda", "Mazda", "Ford" },
              { "2012", "10", "11", "12", "13", "15", "16" },
              { "2013", "10", "11", "12", "13", "15", "16" },
              { "2014", "10", "11", "12", "13", "15", "16" },
              { "2015", "10", "11", "12", "13", "15", "16" },
              { "2016", "10", "11", "12", "13", "15", "16" }
            };

            return View(new IndexViewModel());
        }
```

How can I set this `Model.Table1` property into property in javascript ?

```
<script>
            var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
                data: @Html.Raw(Model.Table1), // this does not work
            });
    </script>
```

Comment: I think you'd want to use Json.NET's `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` method to do this, rather than `Html.Raw`.  `Html.Raw` simply ensures the contents are encoded, but does nothing to ensure proper javascript syntax...

Comment: Thank you, `@Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.Table1)` works :-)